# IIS 7 simple re-write rule

Tags: iis-7

how exactly can i specify that http://mydomain.com be rewritten to http://www.mydomain.com ? A

Comment: Bit vague.  More details would help elicit some answers.  Do you mean that if the public type http://mydomain.com they should be redirected to http://www.mydomain.com ?

Comment: Seems clear to me...  This would be handled with a rewrite rule.  IIS has a rewrite module that will take care of this very easily.  See Scott's answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a redirect from non-www to www using URL rewrite, you can:

- Create a new rule
- Set the "Using" to wildcards.  You can use regex, but these instructions are for wildcards
- Set * for the Pattern
- Add a condition where {HTTP_HOST} matches mydomain.com
- Set the action to "Redirect" with the URL as "http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}
- It's a 301 permanent redirect that you most likely need.  Search engines prefer that.

Comment: An excellent helper site to learn about URL Rewriting can be found at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: That is a good site. Thanks @Dscoduc. I just blogged about this yesterday too, so here's a more detailed walkthrough for this particular situation
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx

Comment: this is what i did, however, i have one issue still. the the entire path is not being changed over, it goes http://mydomain.com/HomePage/ to http://www.mydomain.com.  If I append {R:1} i get errors. btw difference btween {r:0} and {r:1}?

Comment: {R:1} should be the full path.  If your pattern had multiple parts, like domain.(com|net) then you'll have results for {R:1} or others.  You can use the "Test" mini-tools without URL Rewrite in IIS Manager to see the results.  Make sure that you have a trailing / after your domain name in the redirect.

Comment: When you create the rule, you can select the "Canonical Name" rule template and it'll do all this for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the public that type http://mydomain.com into their browsers to be redirected to http://www.mydomain.com then it's quite straightforward.

Firstly you need to add anther A record into your public DNS zone to point mydomain.com to the same IP address as the www A record.

Then you need to configure the host headers for the site in IIS to respond to mydomain.com as well as www.

As good practice (it's been a while since I worked with webservers) in the past we've done this for www, ww, and w to help with typos.

Comment: Web client asks for domain.com and you want them to go to www.domain.com... Not really a DNS function...